# Tkinter Tic Tac Toe Drawing a shape in a certain box

Tags: python, tkinter, tic-tac-toe

I'm a newbie in programming, trying to learn python and I decided to make Tic Tac Toe for my first project. I've made functions for drawing X and O, but I have trouble drawing them in the box I'm clicking. Here's the code so far:

```
ttt = Tk()
ttt.title("Tic Tac Toe")
w = Canvas(ttt, width = 902, height = 902)
w.configure (bg =  "white")
w.pack()

m = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

def drawx(event):
    x, y = event.x, event.y
    w.create_line(49, 49, 249, 249, fill = "black")
    w.create_line(49, 249, 249, 49, fill = "black")

def drawo(event):
    x2, y2 = event.x, event.y
    x0 = x2 - 100
    y0 = y2 - 100
    x1 = x2 + 100
    y1 = y2 + 100
    return w.create_oval(x0, y0, x1, y1)

w.create_line(0, 300, 901, 300, fill = "black") 
w.create_line(0, 601, 901, 601, fill = "black")
w.create_line(300, 0, 300, 901, fill = "black")
w.create_line(601, 0, 601, 901, fill = "black")
```

Here, the shapes will be drawn based on my cursor coordinates, which I know should be modified. Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you complete your code, in particular the binding?

Comment: Read about [Canvas.create_rectangle-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_rectangle-method) and the [find_* methodes](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.find_closest-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the mouse click event to canvas:

```
w.bind('<Button-1>', on_click)
```

Then determine which cell is clicked in `on_click` handler:

```
SIZE = 300
player = 1  # 1 for O, 2 for X

def on_click(event):
    global m
    global player
    row = event.y // SIZE
    col = event.x // SIZE
    # check whether the cell is not filled yet
    if m[row][col] == 0:
        # calculate the center of the cell
        cx = col * SIZE + SIZE // 2
        cy = row * SIZE + SIZE // 2
        # draw X or O based on current player
        if player == 1:
            draw_O(cx, cy)
        else:
            draw_X(cx, cy)
        # set cell is filled
        m[row][col] = player
        # now you need to check whether current player wins
        ...
        # if no one wins, toggle player
        player = 2 if player == 1 else 1

def draw_O(x, y):
    radius = SIZE // 3
    w.create_oval(x-radius, y-radius, x+radius, y+radius, width=5, tag='cell')  # tag is used for resetting the game

def draw_X(x, y):
    radius = SIZE // 3
    w.create_line(x-radius, y-radius, x+radius, y+radius, width=5, tag='cell')
    w.create_line(x+radius, y-radius, x-radius, y+radius, width=5, tag='cell')
```

If you want to reset the game:

```
def reset_game():
    global m
    global player
    # remove all 'O' and 'X'
    w.delete('cell')
    m = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
    player = 1
```

For better design, put all the above logic in a class (inherited from `Canvas`).  Then you can use instance variables instead of global variables.

Comment: Thanks for pretty much giving me most of the code! It's been a huge help. I'm now having a few minor problems. Firstly, I tried binding the reset to <R>, however it's not working. For now, I'm using <Button-3>. Another problem would be stopping the game without closing the canvas so I could actually reset the game. I've also added a global variable k in the on_click for the tie conditions, however it tells me that k has not been defined.

Answer (score 2):

You can "discretize" the `x` and `y` values by integer-dividing and then multiplying with the width of the individual cells (and adding some offset for the center).

```
def drawo(event):
    x2, y2 = event.x, event.y
    x2 = x2 // 300 * 300 + 150
    y2 = y2 // 300 * 300 + 150
    ...
```

Same for `drawx`.

Alternatively, you could use different canvas elements (or buttons, labels or similar) for the different cells in the grid and get the clicked `widget` from the `event`.

Answer (score 0):

To add more detail to tobias_k's answer, the below code will draw an X when the right mouse button is clicked and an O when the left mouse button is clicked.

An improvement in the code could be to use a variable to define the size of the canvas and each X/O rather than hard coding 200 or 300.

```
from tkinter import *

ttt = Tk()
ttt.title("Tic Tac Toe")
w = Canvas(ttt, width = 902, height = 902)
w.configure (bg =  "white")
w.pack()

m = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

def drawx(event):
    print("drawx")
    x, y = event.x, event.y
    x0 = x // 300 * 300 + 50
    y0 = y // 300 * 300 + 50
    x1 = x0 + 200
    y1 = y0 + 200
    #return w.create_oval(x0, y0, x1, y1)
    w.create_line(x0,y0,x1,y1, fill = "black")
    w.create_line(x0,y0+200,x1,y1-200, fill = "black")

def drawo(event):
    print("drawo")
    x, y = event.x, event.y
    x0 = x // 300 * 300 + 50
    y0 = y // 300 * 300 + 50
    x1 = x0 + 200
    y1 = y0 + 200
    return w.create_oval(x0, y0, x1, y1)

w.create_line(0, 300, 901, 300, fill = "black") 
w.create_line(0, 601, 901, 601, fill = "black")
w.create_line(300, 0, 300, 901, fill = "black")
w.create_line(601, 0, 601, 901, fill = "black")

w.bind('<Button-1>',drawo)
w.bind('<Button-3>',drawx)

ttt.mainloop()
```